# How to separate content for unregistred and registred users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

The problem is:

The site has one content for people who have not yet registered and another for those who have already registered and logged in. When I enter the site, I am thrown onto the page **/login** as I have indicated in Spring Security and this page does not allow me to go anywhere until I log in. But I need to throw me at the entrance to the site to the home page for unregistered users where i can view information about the event, and etc, and then register or log in. I almost decided that, I added to the Spring Security class **.loginPage("/index")** instead of **("/login")** + added antMatchers, where he indicated all the pages that an unregistered user can visit. But there was a problem. It is shown in the picture. My styles do not work, it also stops showing pictures.[image]
[image]

I add to antMatchers **"/resources/**"** but this does not help. Also, when I go to the "log in" tab from the main page, and I try to log in by entering my login and password, write an error

> "Request method 'POST' not supported
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'POST' not supported at "

**My Sping Secutiry code before update -**

```
   @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private SimpleAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/runner/**").hasAnyRole("RUNNER","ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/coordinator/**").hasAnyRole("COORDINATOR","ADMIN")
                      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                    .formLogin()
                      .loginPage("/login")
                      .successHandler(successHandler)
                      .permitAll().and()
                    .logout()
                      .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers( "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**","/error");
        }
    }
```

**My Sping Secutiry code after update - the rest is the same**

```
       @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/runner/**").hasAnyRole("RUNNER","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/coordinator/**").hasAnyRole("COORDINATOR","ADMIN")
                  .antMatchers( "/aboutEvent","/marathonCompare","/charityOrgList",
                          "/calculatorBMI","/calculatorBMR","/learnMore","/registerAsRunner","/becomeSponsor","/",
                          "/allResults","/interactiveMap","/becomeRunner","/login","/resources/**").permitAll()
                  .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/index")
                  .successHandler(successHandler)
                  .permitAll().and()
                .logout()
                  .permitAll();
    }
```

**Login Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(){

        return "login/login";
    }
}
```

**Login Page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
          crossorigin="anonymous" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/runnerstyle/register.css}"/>
</head>
<body class="align">

<div class="register-top flex-container">
    <form th:action="@{/index}">
        <button type="submit" class="register-back">Назад</button>
    </form>
    <h1><b>MARATHON SKILLS 2018</b></h1>
</div>

<div class="login-middle">
    <div class="login-text">
        <h2>Форма авторизации<br/></h2>
        <h4>Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь в системе, используя ваш адресс электронной почты<br>
        и пароль.
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>Invalid username or password</p>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
        <p>You've been logged out</p>
    </div>

    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post" class="form-input">
        <table>
            <tr th:class="${param.error} ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'">
                <th><h4>Email:</h4></th>
                <th style="padding-left: 20px">
                    <input type="email" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your email address" size="60px" class="input-field">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:class="${param.error} ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'">
                <th><h4>Password:</h4></th>
                <th style="padding-left: 20px">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your email password" size="60px" class="input-field">
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th style="padding-right: 13vw;">
                    <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
                    <a href="#" th:href="@{'/'}" class="href">Cancel</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="register-bot">
    18 дней 8 часов и 17 минут осталось до старта марофона!
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Index controller**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping({"/","/index",""})
    public String getIndexPage(){
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registerAsRunner")
    public String registerRunner(){
        return "runner/createOrRegister";
    }

    @GetMapping("/learnMore")
    public String getLearnMorePage(){return "learnmore/main";}
}
```

How can I solve this problem and do what I have in mind? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm confused with your screenshots. The browser is complaining that you are requesting `/index` as a style sheet, but isn't that an html page?

Comment: As for your question about Spring Security, you are correct that `permitAll` is the place for specifying endpoints that require no authentication. I'd recommend taking a step back, simplifying your configuration and taking one step at a time. Also, I'm not to sure about the empty string in your @GetMapping for `/index`. Is that necessary?

Comment: This is index.css stylesheet for my index page.And i checked my antMatchers and i have no whitespaces(.Oh,this empty is not necessary,i'll delete it

Comment: Okay. Your browser says that it is requesting `/index` though, not `/index.css`, at least according to the screenshot. (Thank you for clarifying the other items)

Comment: This is all strange, because when I authorize and open all these pages, there are load without errors.And also i tried your advice about add 1 'antMatcher' step by step - nothing works(

Comment: Have you tried starting from Spring Security's sample? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/helloworld

Comment: @jzheaux i solved this problem. I forgot to add .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll() in my configuartion.My css and bootstrap styles works fine now.But images also do not work, although the console shows the status of 200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184356/discussion-between-maxim-sukhodolets-and-jzheaux).